# Extending Activity with a NavigationDrawer Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am attempting to find the best way to have a dual navigationDrawer to be present in all of my activities throughout my application. I don't want to have to create a new instance of the navigation drawers at each activity, so I thought I would create a ComponentsActivity class which extends Activity. I then have each activity extend ComponentsActivity.

This is all dandy and fine, however I show nothing in my sliding drawers because I'm not populating the drawers inside the activity's layout. Of course, removing the xml layout for a navigationdrawer in the actual activity results in no sliding drawers at all, even though the extended ComponentsActivity has the proper layout for navigationDrawers.

so:

```
public class MainActivity extends ComponentsActivity{
...
}
```

and

```
public class ComponentsActivity extends Activity{
... all of my navigationdrawer(s) set-up and creation
}
```

how do i need to set up my xmls in order to make the MainActicity have the populated navigationDrawers from ComponentsActivity's layout? I tried using a merge and an include but  it is not looking like that is correct.

Comment: Why don't you use one Activity and change it's content dynamically using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)? They're available using the SupportLibrary down to API 7.

Comment: I thought about that, and am considering keeping everything as one activity, but would prefer to have multiple activities. I'd like to use the menubar as a specific toolset to the current activity.. I don't know if i could be changing up the actionbar on each fragment change as I could simply have a different actionbar layout for each activity

Comment: You can let your fragments handle their own menus by simply calling _setHasOptionsMenu(true);_ in your fragment's onCreate() method and then _@Override_ the fragment's _onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)_.